# Storing SSH Key for Bamboo Deployments

Tags: bamboo, bitbucket-server

I've setup a Bamboo specs repository to store build and deployment plans. As part of the deployment plan, I'm using the SCP and SSH tasks to copy artifacts and execute commands on a remote server. What is the recommended way to store the SSH key?

- I don't want to store it in the spec, because this would mean that I'm committing credentials to source control.
- If I upload the key using the UI, it gets removed when I update the plan in the specs repo.
- I could use a global variable (which I'm not entirely sure would work), but it seems global variables are available to all plans, which is a security risk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since version 6.3 Bamboo supports usage of Shared credentials for SSH/SCP tasks. You can store your SSH keys in Shared credential and then reuse it at deployment tasks

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Unfortunately, I'm currently stuck on 6.2.1. I'll look into this if/when we upgrade.

Comment: Do you have an example on how to use the shared keys in a `BitbucketServerRepository` ?

Comment: You don't need shared keys for BitbucketServerRepository, Bamboo manages them for you when you configure repository from Bamboo UI.

Comment: Shared credentials are also available to all build plans